# Trying to connect to RDS instance through my ec2 instance from my local machine and coming up with the following error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-rds, tunneling

Tried connecting to the rds instance through the ec2 instance from  and my local machine coming up with an error saying "Permission denied (public key)"

```
ssh -L 3306:db_instance_name.cxtitvmupc3w.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 my_instance_ip


Permission denied(public key)
```

Comment: Can you ssh to the instance without the port redirect? If so, just append the `-L 3306...` to whatever you use to normally connect.

Comment: Yup. It helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is `ssh` saying that you have not provided a private key to establish the ssh session.

You would normally include `-i keyfile.pem` in the command, exactly the same way you would normally ssh to the instance.